# Retrieving Unknown Value using Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm attempting to pull the 'Total Cash Flow From Operating Activities' figure from Yahoo Finance.  The variable "s" can be any symbol in the SP500.  For the most part, the desired output occurs.  However, in some cases, like for AAPL, I can't figure out what it's printing or where it came from.

If "s" is A, the output is 711000000. Correct.

If "s" is AA, the output is 1674000000. Correct.

However, if "s" is AAPL, the output is -416542144. No clue where that comes from.

```
public class CashFlowStatement {
String cashFromOperatingActivities = "Total Cash Flow From Operating Activities";

public CashFlowStatement(String s) {
    String cashFlowStatementURL = ("https://finance.yahoo.com/q/cf?s="+s+"+Cash+Flow&annual");
    String cashFlowStatementTableName = "table.yfnc_tabledata1";
    boolean foundLine = false;

    String line;
    int line2;

    try {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(cashFlowStatementURL).get();

        for (Element table : doc.select(cashFlowStatementTableName)) {
            for (Element row : table.select("tr")) {
                if(foundLine == false)  {
                    Elements tds = row.select("td");
                    for( int j = 0; j < tds.size() - 1; j++)  {
                        if(tds.get(j).text().equals(cashFromOperatingActivities)) {
                            line = tds.get(j+1).text().replaceAll(",","");
                            line = line.substring(0,(line.length())-2);
                            line2 = Integer.parseInt(line)*1000;
                            System.out.println(line2);
                            foundLine = true;
                        }                                  
                    }
                }    
            } 
        }
    }
    catch (IOException ex)  {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an OVERFLOW! The value from the table is 59,713,000. When you multiply it by 1000 - `line2 = Integer.parseInt(line)*1000;` you get a number which is greater than `MAXINT`, thus the negative value. Try use `long` instead `int` for `line2`.